# Which are the legal limits of this function in $x=1$?

Tags: limits

I have this function : $f:D\to \mathbb R$, where $D$ is the maximal domain for this function, 
$f(x)=\frac{(|x|-1)}{(x-1)}$. And has this function a limit in $1$? Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you mean the maximal domain instead of maximal area?

Comment: Do you mean $\;D\;$ is the function's **domain** ?

Comment: Yes, the maxim domain I mean

Comment: "legal limits" - I'm pretty sure there is nothing illegal in maths

Comment: A more interesting question would have been, imo, with the function $\;f(x)=\cfrac{|x-1|}{x-1}\;$ ...

Answer (score 1):

Fill in details:

The limit exists since if $\;x\to 1\;$ then we can take $\;0.8\le x\le 1.2\;$ , for example, and then we always have that

$$|x|=x\implies\lim_{x\to1}\frac{|x|-1}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x-1}{x-1}=1$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought that I have to do lim(x->1,x<1) and lim(x->1,x>1)..But i understood what you had done. Thank you!

Comment: @Mary Do you mean lateral limits instead of legal limits?

Answer (score 0):

If we consider the function $f(x)=\dfrac{|x|-1}{x-1}$ the its maximal domain is $(-\infty,1)\cup(1,0).$ Why? Because the expression makes sense for any real number expect one. We can't divide by zero.

With respect to the limit note that $|x|=x$ for $x\ge 0.$ So  $$f(x)=\dfrac{|x|-1}{x-1}f(x)=\dfrac{x-1}{x-1}=1,\forall x\in (0,1)\cup(1,\infty).$$ The limit at $x=1$ should be clear now.